# Search matching prefix of every word in field in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I need to write `SELECT` statement selecting rows, where prefix of any word from some field matches given pattern. I'm using sqlite, but it's kind of general question.

I came up with two ideas:

```
SELECT (...) FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'phrase%' OR field LIKE '% phrase%'
```

or

```
SELECT (...) FROM table WHERE ' ' || field LIKE '% phrase%'
```

Both look not-so-elegant and when I use more `... OR ... LIKE ...` in one `SELECT` it kills query performance.
Is there a way to handle this better?

Comment: Do you have a list of patterns in a table or is it going to be hardcoded?

Comment: It's hardcoded. It's kind of search field autocomplete under Android.

Comment: And are you searching one field for many values (or patterns) or multiple fields for a single value (or pattern)?

Comment: Multiple fields in multiple tables for one value. I use `UNION` afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the The Full Text Modules; http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field MATCH 'phrase*';
```